# Optaplanner Value Range Provider not getting called

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I would like to know how a Value Range Provider works.

I have a Class Called `Entity`, In that class there are multiple instances, all mapped in the `Solution` like below

```
@PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
public List<Entity> getEntityList() {
    return entityList;
}
```

Now i want to have differnet range values for different `Entity` **objects**. Eg. one will have 0 to 50, other might have 20 to 100 like. So I implemented `@ValueRangeProvider` inside the `Entity` Class.

```
@PlanningEntity()
public class Entity {

@PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"quantityRange"})
public Long getAllocatedWeight() {
    return allocatedWeight;
}

@ValueRangeProvider(id = "quantityRange")
public CountableValueRange<Long> getQuantityRange() {
    return ValueRangeFactory.createLongValueRange(minWeights, maxWeights);
}

}
```

The breakpoint at `getQuantityRange` is never getting called, also the Optaplanner is not considering the range while generating results, but all the drools rules are working fine as intended. All I need is to, statically assign ranges for each entity objects.

> Note : I am using the `InvestmentQuantityTransferMove.java` for stepping
>   from the **investments** example found in the optaplanner Repo. Since
>   my solution is also similar, that the sum of all entity should be
>   exactly equal to a specific value.

Answer (score 0):

Your entity probably isn't being parsed by OptaPlanner, or you'd get a clear exception - or the break point would hit. So one of these 2 conditions isn't met:

- Your Entity needs to have an @PlanningEntity annotation. This is clearly met.
- Your Entity needs to be registered in the `solverConfig.xml` (or java API equivalent) with `<entityClass>`. This is probably the problem.

(If both of these are met and your break point isn't hit, then this is a bug. Create a jira with a reproducer.)

This is a common pitfall, but unfortunately OptaPlanner can't detect if an entity isn't registered (as far as I know, without incurring a heavy boostrap performance cost)...

Comment: Thanks for the support, I checked my XML and it contains the full class name under <entityClass>. Also, all other features (rules) are working on top of this entity, I beleive its a bug in my version, Do you know any version without this issue

Comment: I have never seen this bug, so please [create a jira](https://issues.jboss.org/projects/PLANNER) with a reproducer so I can confirm it's a bug (and fix it).